# How to fix Internal Server Error for BIM 360 using NET Core 2.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to copy `Companies` inside BIM 360 from one account (Source) to another account (Target). The following code creates a Company inside of the Target account with the same properties as the Source account.

```
dynamic createdTargetCompany = await Autodesk.Forge.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient.CallApiAsync(
        "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/" + targetAccountId + "/companies",
        Method.POST,
        new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        Deserialize.DeserializeObject(sourceCompanyInfo.Content, "Company"),
        targetHeaderParams,
        new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        new Dictionary<string, FileParameter>(),
        new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        "application/json");
```

The `createdTargetCompany` variable contains status code `InterServerError` with the following message:

> "{\"code\":2000,\"message\":\"ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint \\"companies_pkey\\"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(15bf4765-73b8-4940-aec4-0bcbeeec2bae) already exists.\n\"}"

I am unsure what the `DETAIL: Key (id)` is. Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like the unique ID (guid) for the company - not sure on the bim API but maybe you need to set the company GUID to null (all zeros) before you create a new record?

Comment: Presumably the `id` of a company must be unique across all companies and all accounts, and the site is interpreting your request as one to create a new company with the exact same internal ID as the existing one. You'll need to be more careful about what "copying" means -- do you want to associate one company with two accounts, or really copy all the company details so you end up with two companies that are effectively the same (but still have different ids)? (I have no idea if the API allows the former, it depends on its data model.)

Comment: Looks like the `id` part of the JSON response contains the company GUID as per: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-:company_id-GET/ - chances are the `POST` request tries to create a company with the same ID as another. The `POST` message looks like it doesn't take an `id` as part of the content but I'd assume that it's a bug/side-effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code I posted in the question above, the `Deserialize.DeserializeObject(sourceCompanyInfo.Content, "Company"),` method now no longer gets the Source's Account Id and Company Id. Removing this feature now creates the Companies in the Target account.

Many thanks to the comments posted regarding this issue.